# the preimage of a submanifold is locally a submanifold: Tangentspace?

Tags: geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f \colon M \to N$ be a smooth map between smooth manifold. Let $C \subset f(M)$ be a submanifold of $N$.

Let $x \in f^{-1}(C)$ and assume that there exists a neighborhood $U \subset M$ of $x$, such that $U \cap F^{-1}(C)$ is a submanifold of $M$.

Can I then prove, that $T_x(f^{-1}(C) \cap U) = d_xf^{-1}(T_{f(x)}C)$?

It is clear, that we have $T_x(f^{-1}(C) \cap U) \subset d_xf^{-1}(T_{f(x)}C)$. So we only need to show the other inclusion. (if it is true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \ dim(M) = m \in \mathbb{N}^*$. We can view tangent vectors on $ \ x \in M \ $ as equivalence classes of curves in this manner: Let $R_x$ be the set of all (continuous) paths $ \ \gamma: J \to M \ $ such that $ \ J \subset \mathbb{R} \ $ is an open interval, $0 \in J$, $\gamma(0) = x \ $ and there exists some chart $ \ z : V \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ around $ \ x \in V \subset M \ $ such that $ \ z \circ \gamma : J \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ is differentiable at $0$, where $J$ is chosen small enough for we to have that $ \ im(\gamma) \subset V$, by continuity. In this way, it is simple to show that $ \ y \circ \gamma : J \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ is differentiable at $0$, for all charts $ \ y : W \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ around $ \ x \in W \subset M$, $\forall \gamma \in R_x$, restricting $\gamma$ to a smaller open interval, if necessary. We define an equivalence relation on $R_x$ setting $ \ \alpha \sim \beta \ $ if and only if there exists some chart $ \ z : V \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ around $ \ x \in V \subset M \ $ such that the derivatives $ \ (z \circ \alpha)'(0) = (z \circ \beta)'(0)$, $\forall \alpha , \beta \in R_x$. Again, it is simple to show that, $\forall \alpha , \beta \in R_x$, if $ \ \alpha \sim \beta$, then $ \ (y \circ \alpha)'(0) = (y \circ \beta)'(0)$, for all charts $ \ y : W \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ around $ \ x \in W \subset M$. Then, the relation $ \, \sim \, $ is an equivalence relation and we set $ \ T_x M = R_x/ \! \! \sim \, $. Also, for each chart $ \ z : V \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ around $ \ x \in V \subset M \ $, we have that the map $ \ d_x z : T_x M \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ such that, $\forall \gamma \in R_x$, $d_x z ([ \gamma ]) = [(z \circ \gamma)'(0)](1)$, is a bijection and we define a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure (addition and scalar multiplication) on $T_xM$ imposing that it is an isomorphism. Let $X$ be a submanifold of $M$. Because every path $ \ \gamma: J \to X \ $ is a path on $M$ too, $ \ \gamma: J \to M \ $, then it is straightforward that $ \ T_xX \subset T_xM$, $\forall x \in X$.

Let $M$ and $N$ be differentiable manifolds and $ \ f: M \to N \ $ be a differentiable function. We define the differential pushforward of $f$ at $ \ x \in M \ $ as a map $ \ d_x f : T_xM \to T_{f(x)}N \ $ such that, $\forall \gamma \in R_x$, $d_xf([\gamma])=[f \circ \gamma]$. Then, $d_xf$ is a linear map.

That being said, let $ \ [\gamma] \in T_x \big( f^{-1} [C] \cap U \big)$. Then $\gamma$ is a path $ \ \gamma : J \to f^{-1} [C] \cap U$, where $J$ is an open interval. Then $ \ d_xf([\gamma]) = [f \circ \gamma] \in T_{f(x)}N$, where $f \circ \gamma$ is a path $ \ f \circ \gamma : J \to N$. For all $ \ t \in J \ $ we have $ \ \gamma(t) \in f^{-1} [C] \cap U \subset f^{-1} [C]$. Hence $ \ (f \circ \gamma) (t) = f \big( \gamma(t) \big) \in C$. Therefore $ \ im(f \circ \gamma) \subset C \ $ and we have that $f \circ \gamma$ is a path $ \ f \circ \gamma : J \to C$. For this reason, $d_xf([\gamma]) = [f \circ \gamma] \in T_{f(x)}C \ $ and we conclude that $ \ [\gamma] \in (d_xf)^{-1}[T_{f(x)}C]$. So, we proved that $ \ T_x \big( f^{-1} [C] \cap U \big) \subset (d_xf)^{-1}[T_{f(x)}C]$.

For the other hand, let $ \ [\gamma] \in (d_xf)^{-1}[T_{f(x)}C]$. Then $ \ [\gamma] \in T_xM$, $\gamma$ is a path $ \ \gamma : J \to M \ $ and $ \ [f \circ \gamma] = d_xf([\gamma]) \in T_{f(x)}C \subset T_{f(x)}N$. Hence, $f \circ \gamma$ is a path $ \ f \circ \gamma : J \to C \ $ and we have that, $\forall t \in J$, $f \big( \gamma(t) \big) = (f \circ \gamma)(t) \in C$, which implies $ \ \gamma(t) \in f^{-1} [C]$. By continuity, we can choose $J$ small enough to have $ \ im(\gamma) \subset U$. For this reason, $\gamma(t) \in f^{-1}[C] \cap U$, $\forall t \in J$. So, we have $ \ im(\gamma) \subset f^{-1}[C] \cap U \ $ and $\gamma$ is really a path $ \ \gamma : J \to f^{-1}[C] \cap U$. Then $ \ [\gamma] \in T_x \big( f^{-1} [C] \cap U \big)$. We proved that $ \ (d_xf)^{-1}[T_{f(x)}C] \subset T_x \big( f^{-1} [C] \cap U \big)$.

Finally, we conclude that $ \ T_x \big( f^{-1} [C] \cap U \big) = (d_xf)^{-1}[T_{f(x)}C]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. There is one thing I'm not quite sure about. You concluded from $d_xf([\gamma]) \in T_{f(x)}C$, that the path $f \circ \gamma$ is contained in $C$ (if $J$ is again small enough). Are we really able to conclude that, or can't we only conclude that $f \circ \gamma \subset N$ and that there exists a path $\mu : I \to C$ s.th. $[\mu]=[f \circ \gamma]$? Why is $f \circ \gamma$ a path in $C$?

Comment: You are right in saying that there exists a path $ \ \mu : I \to C \ $ s.t. $ \ \mu \sim f \circ \gamma$, but you can choose $ \ \mu = f \circ \gamma$.

This is definition. We have that $$[f \circ \gamma] = d_xf([\gamma]) \in T_{f(x)}C = R_{f(x)} (C)/ \! \! \sim$$ as an equivalence class of paths on $C$ that pass trough $f(x)$. By definition we must have that $ \, f \circ \gamma \, $ is a path on $C$.

Comment: I used this definition of tangent spaces because it is a way we can have $ \ T_{f(x)}C \subset T_{f(x)}N \ $ as sets, since we have $ \ C \subset N \ $ as sets. If I used derivations I would have to identify $ \, T_{f(x)}C \, $ with some isomorphic vector subspace of $ \, T_{f(x)}N \, $ as we do not generally have that $ \ T_{f(x)}C \subset T_{f(x)}N \ $ as sets, even if we have $ \ C \subset N \ $ as sets. Think about it.

Comment: I think I see my problem: If $M=N=\mathbb{R}^2$, $S := \{(x,x^2)|x\in \mathbb{R}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $C := \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$. Let $f:= \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ and define the paths $\gamma : I \to S, \gamma(t) =(t,t^2)$ and $\sigma : J \to C, \sigma(t)=(t,0)$. Then $[\sigma]=[\gamma] \in (d_xf)^{-1}(T_{f(x)}C)$, so $d_xf([\sigma])=d_xf([\gamma])\in T_{f(x)}C$, but $f \circ \gamma=\gamma$ is not a path in $C$. That's why I don't really understand why I can choose $\mu = f \circ \gamma$.

Comment: I see now where you missed the point. You are thinking pictorially and missing the definition. You are thinking with the arrow vectors and not with the paths themselves. This is a good example of how to be relevant being wrong. Your example is a really good example and I will follow your notation. The path $\gamma$ you defined is a path on $S$ and a path on $M$, because $ \ im(\gamma) \subset S \subset M$. The path $\sigma$ you defined is a path on $C$ and a path on $M$, because $ \ im(\sigma) \subset C \subset M$.

Comment: Then we have that $ \ \gamma , \sigma \in R_x(M)$, $\gamma \in R_x(S) \ $ and $ \ \sigma \in R_x(C)$, with $ \ x=(0,0)$. But $\gamma$ is not a path on $C$ and, by definition, it can't be a member of $ \, R_x(C)$. Similarly, $\sigma$ can't be a member of $ \, R_x(S)$. Yes, we have that $ \ \gamma \sim \sigma \ $ as paths on $M$, ie, $[\gamma]=[\sigma] \in T_xM = R_x(M)/ \! \! \sim \, $, but this relation is not even defined if we restrict ourselves to paths on $S$ or on $C$. These submanifolds have their own relation, we can say $ \ \sim_S \ $ and $ \ \sim_C \, $.

Comment: It is easy to see that the elements of $ \ R_x(C) \cap R_x(S) \ $ are only constant paths at $ \ x = (0,0)$, because $ \ C \cap S = \{ x \}$. So, we have that $ \ d_xf([\gamma]) = [f \circ \gamma] = [id_{\mathbb{R}^2} \circ \gamma] = [\gamma] \notin T_{f(x)}C$. For this reason we have that $ \ [\gamma] \notin (d_xf)^{-1} \big[ T_{f(x)}C \big]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. I will use the notation of your proof and my first comment. So the important part here is, that $C$ is a submanifold. Since $[f \circ \gamma] \in T_{f(x)}C$ we can conclude that $f \circ \gamma$ is a path in $C$. If we'd say that $f \circ \gamma$ is only a path in $N$ and not in $C$, then we have a contradiction, since $[f \circ \gamma]$ wouldn't be an element in $T_{f(x)}C$, but only in $T_{f(x)}N$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your last affirmative. You are welcome. I am glad that I helped you.